# Windows server 2008 doesn't run .bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2008

I have a problem about some commands in batch file with windows server 2008.

When i try to use `clip` command on command prompt, it works.

But when i use the `clip` command in a batch file and run the batch file, the clip command doesn't work. What should I do on this issue or where is my fault?

EDIT:

```
set wp=D:\workset\xxx\MC_DIM\exchange\

d:
cd %wp%

for %%i in (xxx_to_yyy*.zip) do (
  echo %wp%%%i | clip
)
```

When I try to only `echo` I can take the full path with batch file, also when I use `clip` command from cmd it works but when i create a batch file and try to use it doesn't copy to clipboard. Should it be about privileges or sth ?

Comment: My program gives an answer of 5, but it is supposed to be 4. What am I doing wrong? Good luck answering that, right? It's a little hard to diagnose your problem if you don't show your code.

Comment: I agree with dbenham. We can't provide you with a good answer if you don't provide a good question. Every time you ask a question, you see this phrase in the page: *You ask a vague question, you get a vague answer.* Give us the code, and we'll fix it up for you. But as of now, We can't really do anything to help you.

Comment: @dbenham Okay I am sorry for my mistake :/ I editted my question so maybe this is more clear for better understanding

Comment: Much better :-) Although it would have been better to also describe in what way it doesn't work. But I think I know.

Comment: Are you calling the batch file `clip.*` ?

Answer (score 0):

In my hands, your code works, except it only copies the last file listed to the clipboard. That is because each file listed gets its own pipe to a new CLIP command. Each CLIP command overwrites the result of the prior one.

You need to somehow list the full path to the files and pipe the entire result set to a single CLIP command. The easiest solution that does not use a temporary file is to put parentheses around your FOR statement. Each side of the pipe is executed in its own CMD.EXE process, with ECHO state defaulted back to on. So the command in the DO clause needs the `@` to suppress echoing of the command.

There is no need to include the `%wp%` in your output. The `~f` FOR variable modifier will supply the full path.

```
@echo off
set wp=D:\workset\xxx\MC_DIM\exchange\

d:
cd %wp%

(for %%i in (xxx_to_yyy*.zip) do @echo %%~fi) | clip
```